# Kill Gnome in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I am using my backup computer as a server. It's running Debian and I want to kill everything gnome related to save memory. I'm accessing remotely through ssh.

Any ideas?

Comment: By "killing" you mean disabling for a moment, or removing it entirely?

Comment: Disabling for a moment. Shutting it down, if you will.

Comment: which debian release is it?

Comment: It's debian 6.0.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Gnome Desktop Manager Session is running in the Xserver. Both are just normal services (daemons) your system is starting at boot.

It seems, that X is a child-Process of the Desktop Manager in Debian/Ubuntu. So you have to stop that one (On Debian this might be gdm, on Ubuntu ligthdm)
You can stop gdm for this session by using its init-script, with `sudo` or as root:

```
/etc/init.d/gdm3 stop
```

Or you can remove it from the list of daemons started:

```
update-rc.d <daemon> disable
```

See: http://wiki.debian.org/Daemon

If you are not sure which desktop manager is in use, you can either look for the scripts in /etc/init.d/ or you can type

```
ps -eF | grep dm
```

to search for all running processes containing "dm" (this might yield much more than just your dm though).

Comment: No, that didn't work. Still running like normal.

Comment: Ah I see, I just tried it.
The thing is, if you stop a service, its "children" will be stopped too. I thought it was X -> gdm/lightdm -> gnome/other. 

You have to stop the login manager process. It depends on your Debian version. For Ubuntu and Raspbian its lightdm, but I guess you will see a script called "gdm" in /etc/init.d/.
That's the one. /etc/init.d/gdm stop

Comment: There we go! /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: But it will come back after a restart. For a server, I would deactivate the service with update-rc.d

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to include the working commands?